# Can I program an external numpad to do certain keystrokes?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, latex

So, first of all, I'm a huge Ubuntu noob, and I'm currently running 16.04. I'm primarily a mathematician, and I spend a lot of my day using LaTeX, which can get tedious. So, I'm thinking about using an external numpad or something similar so that I could, say, press "1" on the external numpad, and it would input $...$ with my cursor in the middle, for instance.

Is there a way to do this? I'm worried that the computer wouldn't be able to differentiate between my usual numpad inputs (from my regular keyboard) and the ones from the external numpad.

I guess I was subconsciously inspired by Tom Scott:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIFE7h3m40U

Thanks for any help! (Even if it's a negative answer)

Comment: Ubuntu Podcast's (UK) Mark Johnson once spoke about a project where a second keyboard was added to his system for purposes of using some of its keys as programmable macros. He mentioned where he based his work, and mentioned he could use any keys. I took notice as I have two keyboards attached (*the one I like and the other for media key functions my beloved keyboard lacks*). I'd love to follow up & use more of my second keyboard, I just haven't got around to it.

Comment: Here is a question on [Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/509000/can-i-launch-macros-and-shortcuts-from-a-second-keyboard-on-linux) that may help answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use tools like `xmodmap` and `xkb` to modify the actual behavior of your keyboard, it's sort of like using a constant in a formula when what you really wanted was a variable.

Instead of approaching the problem that way, take a look at using a desktop automation tool which can add layers of power and flexibility to your to workflow.

[AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) is probably exactly what what you're looking for.

AutoKey allows you to create phrases which are triggered when you type an abbreviation or press a hotkey. For instance, you could create a phrase with the contents of `$<cursor>$` and trigger it with an abbreviation of `$$`.

When you type `$$` followed by white space, AutoKey would replace it with `$$` and leave the cursor positioned between the two dollar signs.

While this is a very trivial example, the replacement phrases can be arbitrarily large and complex and you can also use hotkeys such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd> to trigger them.

You can do all of this using the AutoKey GUI to set it up with no programming required.

If you require more selective application, you can define a window filter so that this particular abbreviation or hotkey only works when the current window is running a particular program such as a math editor. In any other window, the abbreviation would not be recognized and would be passed literally to the application running in that window.

AutoKey can also trigger scripts written in Python3 which can do most of the things you can do with a keyboard and a mouse to automate repetitive tasks. For that, you need to have or learn some very basic Python3 programming skills.

AutoKey has many powerful and advanced options and features, but they won't get in the way of defining a bunch of shortcuts for common math notations.
When AutoKey issues mouse and keyboard events, most programs and desktop environments  can't tell it's not you doing them manually, so it works with almost all programs and Linux desktops.

For now, if you want to try AutoKey, don't install it using your Ubuntu package manager. Ubuntu offers an ancient version which has a lot of bugs. [Here](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Installing) are instructions for installing the current version.

Once Ubuntu 20.04 comes out, the new version will be available through your package manager again.

AutoKey is largely independent of specific distributions, so the new version will probably work with Ubuntu 16.04. If it doesn't, you can install the version that comes with 16.04 using your package manager or ask us for help.

You can visit our support forum [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/autokey-users).