How to use external keyboard as macropad in ubuntu
I am working on latex, Video Editing and Libre office oftenly. I have my own shortcuts for most of the repetitive task. Some times it will be hard for memorizing it. So i planned to use external keyboard as macropad. I used GPTs for configuring but it did not went well.
Kindly tell me the ways of configuring external keyboard as macropad.
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal


You've not provided the basic software stack details (ie. what Ubuntu product & release you're using), but if I wanted to do what you wanted, I'd look for and re-listen to a Ubuntu Podcast episode where Mark Johnson outlined what he did with a Ubuntu Desktop project (and then read his blogs on doing it).

Updated software details. Can you share the link of Mark Johnson podcast link

I can't recall what season/episode that was on, I'd say it was in the teens with regards season but as stated in prior comment, I'd have to look for it, which is why I provided what I recall for searching (name of panel presenter & podcast) or terms I'd use to look for it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209127/can-i-program-an-external-numpad-to-do-certain-keystrokes shows another like question  ... I've meant to use that myself... just never got around to it

A very relevant question. It is strange why this proves to be very difficult. Here is a blog post that may get you started in having a press on a separate keypad/keyboard execute a script: https://medium.com/@etdu/programming-a-macro-keypad-for-ubuntu-e430451f5e43. The example shows a simple script that launches a program. You will need to have the script send keystrokes  for triggering the actions in your application. That, you can do with a keyboard automation tool (for example dotool or ydotool, or xdotool if you use Xorg).
